# Can a set be formed from continuous region?

Tags: general-topology

I have a continuous region which is defined as all the area represented by $B$. I would like to know if I can say a 'subset' region to another region inside that shape like $A \subset B$?

Can a continous region "an area" be called a set? I want to verify this.

[image]

Comment: Why not? It is certainly a set of points

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So infinite points?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't call a set an "area".  "Area" is a number, measuring the size of a "set" or "region".

Comment: @user247327 This is exactly what I was thinking, area is a measure, so in measure theory we assign certain measure to a set. So can I say a subset region instead of a subset area?

Comment: You can definitely call this a set of points. Any region you can make will have some representation whose solutions can be described as members of some set.

Comment: Define continuous region.

Comment: @WilliamElliot a region with no holes.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER.  Complete the definition.  You've yet to define region.

Comment: @WilliamElliot region: bounded set of points. So continuous region, bounded set of point with the topological relation between neighboring points.

Comment: I feel like it makes little sense to discuss things without following proper terminology or definitions. There are some terms getting randomly mixed with each other.

Comment: @Zest, please do care to clarify, so I can correct my mistakes.